# WSO2 CEP Siddhi: CPU Utilization increases to 100%

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

The CPU Utilization increases to 100% when we using any Execution plan for any input stream.

1. Create a new Stream with one long payload attribute.
2. Create a new Execution Plan like this:

   @Plan:name('ExecutionPlan')
   @Plan:trace('false')
   @Plan:statistics('false')
   @Import('test.stream:1.0.0')
   define stream input1 (TRADENO long)
3. Run simulate with 10 events per second.
4. Look at CPU Utilization

   - PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
   - 3063 cep 20 0 3916436 746884 20296 S 101.3 19.2 34:02.47 java
5. When I remove import of the stream 'test.stream' the CPU utilisation go to zero.
6. jConsole shows a Siddhi executer Thread uses 95-100% of CPU.
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtIow.png)

How to reduce CPU utilization? 
WSO2CEP viersion is 4.1.0
Java version 8.

Comment: Question Review: There is no clear question to your post.  Try asking a specific question for the community to answer, also give enough information for the community to recreate your issue.

Comment: What version of WSO2CEP are you using?

Comment: There is no such problem in 4.2.0-RC1 Version.